# transfer files from S3 bucket to BigQuery every minute using runtime parameter

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i'd like to transfer data from an S3 bucket to BQ every minute using the `runtime` parameter to define which folder to take the data from but i get `: Missing argument for parameter runtime.`

the parameter is defined under the `--params` with `"data_path"`

```
bq mk \
--transfer_config \
--project_id=$project_id \
--data_source=amazon_s3 \
--display_name=s3_tranfer \
--target_dataset=$ds \
--schedule=None \
--params='{"destination_table_name_template":$ds,
"data_path":"s3://bucket/test/${runtime|\"%M\"}/*",
"access_key_id":"***","secret_access_key":"***","file_format":"JSON"}'
```

Comment: Hi @yonatan gershon, can you try this format `mytable_{run_time|\"%m\"}` in your bq cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have to add the `run_time` in the `destination_table_name_template`
so the cmd line works like this:

```
bq mk \
--transfer_config \
--project_id=$project_id \
--data_source=amazon_s3 \
--display_name=s3_transfer \
--target_dataset=demo \
--schedule=None \
--params='{"destination_table_name_template":"demo_${run_time|\"%Y%m%d%H\"}",
"data_path":"s3://bucket/test/{runtime|\"%M\"}/*",
"access_key_id":"***","secret_access_key":"***","file_format":"JSON"}'
```

the runtime has to be the same as the partition_id. above the partition is hourly. the records in the files have to belong to the that partition_id or the jobs will fail. to see your partition ids use:

```
SELECT table_name, partition_id, total_rows
FROM `mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE partition_id IS NOT NULL
```

but, important to mention. it's not a good idea to rely on this service for an every minute ingestion into BigQuery since your jobs get queued and can take several minutes. the service seems to be designed to run only once every 24H.